# Matplotlib: Plot 2d array radially to make 3d Scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am looking to make a plot similar to the one [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159942/how-do-you-radially-sweep-out-a-1d-array-to-plot-3d-figure-in-python-to-repr), with the simple difference that I would like to to set the distance from the center for each point.  Ie, given a slice of the plot is a circle, where I would like each of the points to be at a definable distance from the center.

What I a starting with, given a simple modification of the previously mentioned answer:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
step = 0.04
maxval = 1.0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
# u here would define the desired distance from radial axis
# u=np.array([0,1,2,1,0,2,4,6,4,2,1])
v=np.array([4,4,6,3,6,4,1,4,4,4,4])
r=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
f=interp1d(r,u)

# walk along the circle
p = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,len(r))
R,P = np.meshgrid(r,p)
# transform them to cartesian system
X,Y = R*np.cos(P),R*np.sin(P)

Z=f(R)

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)#, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_xticks([])
fig.savefig(str(output_prefix + '3d..png'), dpi=(200))
```

[image]
What I would like to plot (apologies for the blurred sketch):
 [image]

I have tried using interp2d to add the `u` variable commented out above, but no luck.  Changing `Z` to the array `u` threw the error that X, Y, and Z must be the same size (`"Argument 'zs' must be of same size as 'xs' "`, understandably as X and Y are now interpolated) What do I need to do? Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you meant in your question.
I made `v` to be the offset of the center of the circles in x-axis.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
step = 0.04
maxval = 1.0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
# v here would define the desired distance from radial axis
u=np.array([0,1,2,1,0,2,4,6,4,2,1])
v=np.array([4,4,6,3,6,4,1,4,4,4,4])
r=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
f=interp1d(r,u)

# walk along the circle
V = np.tile(v, (len(u), 1))
p = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,len(r))
R,P = np.meshgrid(r,p)
# transform them to cartesian system
X,Y = V + R*np.cos(P),R*np.sin(P)

Z=f(R)

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)#, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_xticks([])
plt.show()
```