# Radially 'sweep out' a 2D contour plot to create a 3D plot (Python, Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have three 1D arrays, which represent radius, height, and an intensity measured at that point. I have plotted these to create a 2D contour map. A simple example of the way in which the data is stored is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
y = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
intensity = [5,6,8,9,9,11,15,5,2]

plt.xlabel('Radius')
plt.ylabel('Height')

plt.tricontourf(x,y,intensity)
plt.colorbar(label='Intensity')
plt.show()
```

[image]

(I have had to use plt.tricontourf rather than plt.contour, since the z data is not 2D)

I am looking to create a 3D plot by 'sweeping' the 2D plot through 360 degrees, creating a disk which is azimuthally symmetric. The image below illustrates what I am trying to do...

[image]

...with the data interpolated smoothly through the 360 degrees.

There are a couple of similar questions, notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159942/how-do-you-radially-sweep-out-a-1d-array-to-plot-3d-figure-in-python-to-repr), but this does not use three sets of data to create the contours.

Comment: basically you want to use intensity to color your 3d plot right?

Comment: In your example I do not see a defined "surface". If you plot it you would not be able to observe the inner layers closer to the z axis. Could you provide an example as sample output?

Comment: @Z Li yes you are right. However, in my full data set the intensities decrease at larger radii. Lowering the alpha would enable the inner brighter regions to be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you cannot rotate a 2D plot and get a 3D surface. You can only rotate a 2D curve and get a 3D surface. If this is the case, you could do it as:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
N = 100
r = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
z = np.sqrt(1 - r**2)
intensity = np.linspace(0, 1, N).reshape(1, -1)

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi-1e-3, N)
X = np.outer(np.cos(theta), r)
Y = np.outer(np.sin(theta), r)
Z = np.repeat(z.reshape(1, -1), N, axis = 0)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=cm.jet(np.repeat(intensity, N, axis = 0)))
ax.axes.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)
plt.show()
```

In the code I rotated a curve to create half a unit sphere and color it according to intensity:
[image]

to

[image]

If you insist on plotting all the points, I would suggest a 3d scatter plot, I did some linear interpolation to show more points than the original 9:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
y = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
intensity = [5,6,8,9,9,11,15,5,2]
# number of points to interpolate in 3d space
N = 36
# number of points to interpolate in 2d space
N_2d = 10

f = interp2d(x, y, intensity)
# sample along the radius
r = np.linspace(1,3,N_2d)
# sample along z
z = np.linspace(1,3,N_2d)
intensity = f(r, z)
r,z = np.meshgrid(r, z)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
X = np.outer(np.cos(theta), r)
Y = np.outer(np.sin(theta), r)
Z = np.repeat(z.reshape(1, -1), N, axis = 0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(X, Y, Z, c=np.tile(intensity.T, N).T, alpha = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! The scatter plot approach has worked very well. And by increasing  N and the steps in the r/z linspace, I can essentially make it look like a 3D shape rather than individual points.